# Ranet Olap PIVOT GRID

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, pivot, olap, pivotviewer

I want to use Cell Editing Writeback feature([Ranet Olap PIVOT GRID Write back](http://www.galantis.com/ranet/writeback.html)) of Ranet Olap PIVOT GRID. They don't have the proper documentation for this. If anyone has any experience on this control please help me.

Thanks in advance.
Liyo Jose.

Go the answer...

1. Create Writeback Partition
   a) Start the SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS)
   b) In SQL Server BIDS open the database Adventure Works (File -> Open -> Analysis Services Database...)
   c) In the tree Solution Explorer select the cube Adventure Works
   d) On the tab Partitions select group of measures Sales Targets
   e) Create for her Writeback Partition (call the local menu Writeback Setting...)
   f) Process the cube Adventure Works

Next, run Ranet OLAP Sample Web Application and pass the settings:

1. Set the Connection string
   a) Click on the tab [Configurations] and set OLAPConnectionString
   For example:
   Provider=MSOLAP.4;Data Source=server\sql2008r2;Catalog=Adventure Works DW;
2. Set the Mdx Query
   a) Click on the tab [Mdx Query] and copy

   SELECT 
   HIERARCHIZE([Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Quarter].Members) DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME, HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME, CUSTOM_ROLLUP, UNARY_OPERATOR, KEY0 ON 0, 
   HIERARCHIZE(CrossJoin([Employee].[Employees].[(All)].Members, [Sales Territory].[Sales Territory].Levels(0).Members)) DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME, HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME, CUSTOM_ROLLUP, UNARY_OPERATOR, KEY0 ON 1 
   FROM 
   [Adventure Works] 
   WHERE ([Measures].[Sales Amount Quota]) 
   CELL PROPERTIES BACK_COLOR, CELL_ORDINAL, FORE_COLOR, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS, FORMAT_STRING, VALUE, FORMATTED_VALUE, UPDATEABLE, ACTION_TYPE
3. Set the Update Script
   a) Click on the tab [Mdx Update Script] and copy

   UPDATE CUBE [Adventure Works]
   SET 
   (
    [Measures].[Sales Amount Quota]
   ,<%[Date].[Calendar]%>
   ,<%[Employee].[Employees]%>
   ,<%[Sales Territory].[Sales Territory]%>
   )
   = <%newValue%>

In the <%[Dimension].[Hierarchy]%> - the cell coordinate in the visible part of the table. If you remove the hierarchy of the rows or columns - it should be removed from the Update Script. The coordinates for the invisible hierarchies are defined explicitly or by any algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example of settings is described in the PDF-document [Ranet OLAP: Editing data in the pivot grid](http://www.galantis.com/download?did=114)

The document includes the following sections:

1. Setting up the Writeback partition for the database Adventure Works

   Setting up the MDX query and the UPDATE SCRIPT

   Editing data in the Pivot Grid

   Examples of the code

Use the version Ranet OLAP 2.5 for Silverlight.